# Converting local timestamp to UTC timestamp in Java

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, timestamp

I have a milliseconds-since-local-epoch timestamp that I'd like to convert into a milliseconds-since-UTC-epoch timestamp. From a quick glance through the docs it looks like something like this would work:

```
int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
long newTime = oldTime - offset;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `Calendar` to get what the offset was at the local Epoch, then add that to the local-epoch timestamp.

```
public static long getLocalToUtcDelta() {
    Calendar local = Calendar.getInstance();
    local.clear();
    local.set(1970, Calendar.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    return local.getTimeInMillis();
}

public static long converLocalTimeToUtcTime(long timeSinceLocalEpoch) {
    return timeSinceLocalEpoch + getLocalToUtcDelta();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't account for DST at all.

Comment: @Quartz - it doesn't have to, since we're dealing with deltas from the Epoch.  Do you have an example (zone and timeSinceLocalEpoch) where this fails?

Answer (score 9):

Sadly, this seems to be the best way to do this:

```
public static Date convertLocalTimestamp(long millis)
{
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
    long localMillis = millis;
    int offset, time;

    c.set(1970, Calendar.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    // Add milliseconds
    while (localMillis > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    {
        c.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        localMillis -= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    c.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (int)localMillis);

    // Stupidly, the Calendar will give us the wrong result if we use getTime() directly.
    // Instead, we calculate the offset and do the math ourselves.
    time = c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    time += c.get(Calendar.SECOND) * 1000;
    time += c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 60 * 1000;
    time += c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    offset = tz.getOffset(c.get(Calendar.ERA), c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK), time);

    return new Date(millis - offset);
}
```

(I know that this is several months past post date, but it's a problem that is very useful to solve when working with text messages on Android.  dave's answer is wrong.)

Answer (score 3):

Using Joda Time it would be like this :

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("local");

dt.getMillis();
```

EDITED:  Sorry, this is the correct version :

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(timestamp, DateTimeZone.forID("local");

dt.getMillis();
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Chris Lercher hit the nail on the head, but he only made it in a short comment, so I wanted to expand on it.

Imagine two stopwatches; one is somewhere where UTC is the local time on Jan 1, 1970, and the other stopwatch is local to your area (let's say that it's in New York, 5 hours after UTC). At *UTC midnight*, on Jan 1, 1970, the UTC stopwatch is started. 5 hours later, your local stopwatch is started. Those two stopwatch times differ by some amount, **determined only by what the difference between UTC was from your local time at *local midnight* on Jan 1, 1970**. Any daylight-saving shenanigans, since then, have no bearing on the difference between those stopwatches. So, any DST corrections for your *present* time or for the times you're *converting*, are irrelevant. *All you need is how much later your local stopwatch started on Jan 1, 1970*.

As Chris pointed out, this is just: getOffset(0L), so:

```
int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(0L);
long newTime = oldTime - offset;
```

... should work fine. *However*....

To help really grasp this, note this: that  "0L" in getOffset() is the milliseconds since the UTC epoch (which is the only *real* epoch). So, your offset variable is going to have the number of seconds of offset at midnight UTC (ie, when it was, say, 19:00 on 12/31/1969 in New York). If your local time switched to/from daylight-saving in those last hours before *local* midnight, then getOffset(0L) wouldn't be correct. You need to know what your daylight-saving status was at *local* midnight, not UTC's midnight.

I'd be surprised if this were the case, anywhere (ie, any timezone which changed to/from DST between their local midnight and UTC midnight of Jan 1, 1970). However, just for fun, a cheap hack to help guard against this would be to check if the offset changed in those hours:

```
// Offset at UTC midnight
int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(0L);
long newTime = oldTime - offset;
// Offset at Local midnight
int localMidnightOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(-offset);
```

Here, localMidnightOffset will be what the timezone offset was at a time -offset milliseconds after UTC midnight in 1970. If no DST change happened, then localMidnightOffset will equal offset, and you're done. If some DST change *did* occur, then you might have to hunt around... probably keep doing a

```
localMidnightOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(-localMidnightOffset)
```

until it stops changing... and hope you don't get caught in an endless loop. I'm curious to see if anybody has a guaranteed-converging solution.

Kinda makes you wish the world were flat, huh?

Comment: best answer i've seen on SO for a while

Answer (score 2):

No, that definitely won't work - it doesn't take DST into account. You can't just use `getOffset(oldTime)` either, as the DST may have changed between the two...

You could use `getOffset(oldTime)` to get an initial guess at the timestamp, then check `getOffset(utcTime)` to see whether they're the same or not. It gets fun, basically.

[Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) *should* support this using [`DateTimeZone.getOffsetFromLocal`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getOffsetFromLocal(long)) but that's [slightly broken](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2952991&group_id=97367&atid=617889#) (IMO) around DST transitions.

All of this really depends on what you mean by "milliseconds since local epoch". If you *really* mean elapsed milliseconds since local 1970, you could just find out the offset at that date, and apply that regardless. Typically (IME) a "local" millis value doesn't mean quite that though - it means "the number of millis to get to a particular date and time (e.g. April 9th 2010, 18:06pm) in UTC, but in respect of a different time zone". In other words, it can represent ambiguous or impossible date/time combinations based on DST transitions.

Comment: But I think you could use `getOffset(0L)` All that matters is the time difference back then, at the start of the epoch - and I hope, that DST transition didn't occur on Jan 1st.

Answer (score 0):

```
static final long localTimeZoneoffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(0L);
static final long dstOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings();

long offsetOftime = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(time.getTime());
long timeinmilli = 0L; 
if(offsetOftime != localTimeZoneoffset)
   timeinmilli = time.getTime()+localTimeZoneoffset+dstOffset;
else
   timeinmilli = time.getTime()+localTimeZoneoffset;
return new Timestamp(timeinmilli);
```

This worked for me to convert to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you i have try this way. Please comment me if there is any best and optimize way to convert local time to UTC timestamp.

```
String mDate= "Jul 21,2016 1:23 PM";
String mDateFormat =""MMM d,yyyy h:mm a";
```

**Call :** `getConvertedTimeToUTC(mDate,mDateFormat);`

```
     public String getConvertedTimeToUTC(String ourDate, String mDateFormat) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat(mDateFormat);
                fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                Date value = fmt.parse(ourDate);
                if (value != null)
                    return String.valueOf(value.getTime() / 1000);
                else
                    return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ourDate = "00-00-0000 00:00";
            }
            return ourDate;
        }
```

Here is the result : [(Ref : check conversion)](http://www.epochconverter.com/)

```
Result 1469107380
GMT: Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:23:00 GMT
Your time zone: Thursday 21 July 2016 06:53:00 PM IST GMT+5:30
```