# How to convert year month day to proper UTC milliseconds from the epoch?

Tags: java, date, utc

I am trying to convert a date into milliseconds with the following code:

```
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    gc.clear();
    gc.set(1900, 1, 1);

    long left = gc.getTimeInMillis();
```

I get `left=-2206310400000`, but when I check [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/), I should get -2208988800000.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609360/converting-local-timestamp-to-utc-timestamp-in-java

Comment: Note: timestamps use POSIX time, not UTC time.  The difference these days is about a half minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using 1 for the month number, which means February.

You mean

```
gc.set(1900, 0, 1);
```

From [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

> month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

Yes, the Java date/time API is broken. If you're doing any significant amount of work in dates/times, I'd suggest you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead.

```
long left = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long epochMillis = OffsetDateTime.of(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)
                            .toInstant()
                            .toEpochMilli();

        System.out.println(epochMillis);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-2208988800000
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/F0rwqe)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>