# Convert a date and time string according to UTC format

Tags: android, date, time, utc

I am having a date string `2012-11-21 13:11:25` which I get from local database. I have to convert this according to `UTC` settings and display it on a particular screen. So if its `GMT+05:30` it should be displayed as `2012-11-21 18:41:25` on the screen. How can I do this conversion. I have checked some of the questions but that didn't work out.

I am able to get a Date object that returns something like `Wed Nov 21 13:11:25 GMT+05:30 2012`  after this I need to get the time as `18:41:25` and date as `11-21-2012`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can check this out:

[Convertion][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609360/converting-local-timestamp-to-utc-timestamp-in-java


Hope this helps.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your `df` and `inputFmt` must use the same format.

But I think you should do it like this:

```
    Date myDate = new Date();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    calendar.setTime(myDate);
    Date time = calendar.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat outputFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyy h:mm a zz");
    String dateAsString = outputFmt.format(time);
    System.out.println(dateAsString);
```

Answer (score 23):

Get UTC from current time :

```
public String getCurrentUTC(){
        Date time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat outputFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        outputFmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        return outputFmt.format(time);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Best way to get formatted string of Date in required format is

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String formatted = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: Why is this better than the previous answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
    //This is my input date 

    String dtStart = "2019-04-24 01:22 PM";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = format.parse(dtStart);
        getDateInUTC(date)

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

//This Method use for convert Date into some UTC format

```
public static String getDateInUTC(Date date) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            String dateAsString = sdf.format(date);
            System.out.println("UTC" + dateAsString);
            return dateAsString;

        }
```