# Android how to convert string date format into UTC?

Tags: android

I need to convert string date format into utc, I have tried to convert as like below, but its not working correctly dont know what mistake i have done

```
String str_date = "03-06-2015 00:00:00";
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date;
    try {
        date = df.parse(dateStr);
        stratingdate = df.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    LogUtil.d("starting date" + stratingdate);
```

so please help me to find out the issue

Comment: explain properly what do you mean by starting date and time???

Comment: i have edited my question check it out now

Comment: what's  df in `String da = df.format(date);`? should be `formatter`?

Comment: @Xcihnegn i have edited my question, kindly look it out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473073/convert-a-date-and-time-string-according-to-utc-format try this

Comment: Yes i have already check that link. but not able to understand where i need to pass my string date

Comment: now the codes looks ok, so what the stratingdate is after converting?

Comment: @Xcihnegn 03-06-2015 12:00:00 its wrong, it should be 02-06-2015 18:30:00

Comment: Check this [link](https://biese.wordpress.com/2014/02/28/the-easy-way-to-convert-local-time-to-utc-time/)

Answer (score 0):

In Simple date Formate, it accepted format like 03/04/2015 00:00:00 ,it is successfully run..

```
String str_date = "03/06/2015 00:00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date;
try {
    date = df.parse(str_date);
    stratingdate = df.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

LogUtil.d("starting date" + stratingdate);
```