# How to convert java.sql.Timestamp to UTC-based string?

Tags: java, clojure

When you call `.toString` on a `java.sql.Timestamp` instance, you get back a formatted string in your local time zone.  I want a formatted string based off of UTC, like the one that I see in the representation.  How can I get the one from the representaion?

```
user> (def timestamp (doto (java.sql.Timestamp. 1366156869000) (.setNanos 42)))
#'user/timestamp
user> timestamp
#inst "2013-04-17T00:01:09.000000042-00:00"
user> (str timestamp)
"2013-04-16 20:01:09.000000042"
```

I know that I could use a `DateFormat`, but presumably this is a common issue so I'm wondering if there's something else?

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [Converting local timestamp to UTC timestamp in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609360/converting-local-timestamp-to-utc-timestamp-in-java)

Or you can also Joda time to convert local time to UTC which is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Joda time loses precision (the nanos will disappear), so that isn't an option.  I don't think you need to do any conversion because you already have the value as UTC -- the string conversion is taking out of UTC.